# Passing two JSON data in HttpResponse

Tags: json, django

How to properly return two JSON data? I tried this code below but it returned an error which is `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`. I tried looking in the console, here is the sample result:

```
{"landarea": ["93.405145"], "brgy": ["BAAN KM 3"], "taxdec": ["08-11-0001-02746"]}{"mydescription": ["Built-up Areas"]}
```

Obviously, `{` is found there.

Here is my views.py:

```
def pins_info(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        getpin = request.GET.get('pin', None)
        keyvals = OrderedDict([
            ('taxdec', 'landproperty__ctaxdec'),
            ('brgy', 'ssectionid__sbrgyid__cbrgyname'),
            ('landarea', 'narea')
        ])
        keyvals1 = OrderedDict([
            ('mydescription', 'description')
        ])

        m = ButuanMaps.objects.filter(clandpin=getpin).values_list(*keyvals.values())
        reference = ButuanMaps.objects.get(clandpin=getpin).geom
        within = ErosionMap.objects.filter(geom__contains=reference).values_list(*keyvals1.values())
        #result_list = list(chain(m, within))
        result = dict(zip(keyvals, zip(*m)))
        result1 = dict(zip(keyvals1, zip(*within)))
        data = json.dumps(result, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        data1 = json.dumps(result1, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
        return HttpResponse({data,data1}, content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not create a json object that encapsulates both objects from your example:

```
var result = 
{
     "land" : {
       "landarea": ["93.405145"], 
       "brgy": ["BAAN KM 3"], 
       "taxdec": ["08-11-0001-02746"]
     },
     "description" : {
       "mydescription": ["Built-up Areas"]
     }
}
```